# How to populate second option list based on first one

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Okay, first things first. I already know how to populate the second option list based on first selection with `jQuery` and `AJAX` request.

My problem begins after the user submits the form. Let's say you submit the form but it rejects your request because you forgot some input. In this case I have to populate the second option list without the user selecting the first one again.

First I inject a `request` object to the form class and if the request is post and value is bigger than 0, I populate the second option list.

Is this the correct way? How can I make this operation better?

```
<?php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $city = $this->request->get('fos_user_registration_form_city', 0);
    // if city selected then populate provinces...
    if($city)
        $provinces = $this->getProvinces($city);
    else
        $provinces = [0 => '...'];

    $builder->add('provinces', 'choice', array(
            'choices'  => $provinces,
            'label' => 'form.province',
            'preferred_choices' => array(0),
            'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
            'required' => true,
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form events :  PRE_SET_DATA POST_SUBMIT
The type would now look like:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Sport;
class SportMeetupType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('sport', 'entity', array(
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Sport',
            'placeholder' => '',
        ));
    ;
    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Sport $sport = null) {
        $positions = null === $sport ? array() : $sport->getAvailablePositions();

        $form->add('position', 'entity', array(
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Position',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices'     => $positions,
        ));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
            $data = $event->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getSport());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('sport')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $sport = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $sport);
        }
    );
} }
```

And in your twig template you can use somme javascript to auto update form with the new data :

```
{# app/Resources/views/Meetup/create.html.twig #}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.sport) }}    {# <select id="meetup_sport" ... #}
{{ form_row(form.position) }} {# <select id="meetup_position" ... #}
{# ... #}
{{ form_end(form) }}
<script>
  var $sport = $('#meetup_sport');
  // When sport gets selected ...
  $sport.change(function() {
  // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
 var $form = $(this).closest('form');
 // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
 var data = {};
 data[$sport.attr('name')] = $sport.val();
 // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
 $.ajax({
 url : $form.attr('action'),
 type: $form.attr('method'),
 data : data,
 success: function(html) {
   // Replace current position field ...
    $('#meetup_position').replaceWith(
      // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
      $(html).find('#meetup_position')
    );
     // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
   }
   });
 });
 </script>
```

For more info you can see [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)